How to update Boost for Visual Studio
I have Boost 1.86 installed in C:\Dev\Boost_1_86_0. The way I setup Boost in CMake is the following:
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
if(MSVC)
    add_definitions("-DHAS_BOOST -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601")
endif()
set(Boost_DEBUG 1) 
find_package(Boost 1.86 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

It works, but now I want to update Boost to 1.87. So, I unpacked new Boost into C:\Dev\Boost_1_87_0. In this folder I firstly did
bootstrap
.\b2

in regular console. Then I recall that it may be done in Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022 so it may configure somehow Visual Studio files. So, I repeated command in Developer Command Prompt:
b2 --clean-all -n
bootstrap
b2

Also I updated BOOST_ROOT Windows environment var to be C:\Dev\Boost_1_87_0. The find_package command now is:
find_package(Boost 1.87 REQUIRED)

Now CMake says it can't find Boost 1.87 with the following output:
...
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1706 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1707 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = "ON"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1708 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = "ON"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1709 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1710 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1711 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1743 ] BOOST_ROOT = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1744 ] ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = "C:\Dev\Boost_1_87_0"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1745 ] BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1746 ] ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1747 ] BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1748 ] ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1836 ] location of version.hpp: C:/Dev/Boost_1_86_0/boost/version.hpp
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1876 ] Boost_VERSION = "108600"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1877 ] Boost_VERSION_STRING = "1.86.0"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1878 ] Boost_VERSION_MACRO = "108600"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1879 ] Boost_VERSION_MAJOR = "1"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1880 ] Boost_VERSION_MINOR = "86"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1881 ] Boost_VERSION_PATCH = "0"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1882 ] Boost_VERSION_COUNT = "3"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1906 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = "lib"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1907 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:953 ] _boost_COMPILER = "-vc143;-vc142;-vc141;-vc140" (guessed)
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1943 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2021 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "-x64" (detected)
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2025 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2026 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-gd"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2086 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "C:/Dev/Boost_1_86_0/stage/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2087 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "C:/Dev/Boost_1_86_0/stage/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH"
1> [CMake] CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
1> [CMake]   Could NOT find Boost: Found unsuitable version "1.86.0", but required is at
1> [CMake]   least "1.87" (found C:/Dev/Boost_1_86_0, )
...

How to fix it?

You seem to forgot to install Boost, with ./b2 install command. Variable BOOST_ROOT should point to the installation directory, not to the source one.

Thanks, @Tsyvarev. I should have installed Boost and set env var to this installation folder, for example:
b2 --prefix=c:\Dev\Boost_1_87_0_build install

